Determinant of a 2 X 2 matrix is not working
I'm trying to find the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix with analytical expression, but replacing most of the terms by numerical values, but having an error message which I don't understand! The MWE is below:
ele11 = {{1/
2 a (2 I (cosb^2 + sinb^2) (cosb^2 Ir\[Lambda]6 + 
     cosb Ir\[Lambda]5 sinb + Ir\[Lambda]7 sinb^2) v + 
  a (6 cosb^3 (-Rl\[Lambda]6 + Rl\[Lambda]7) sinb + 
     6 cosb (Rl\[Lambda]6 - Rl\[Lambda]7) sinb^3 + 
     cosb^4 (Rl\[Lambda]5 + \[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4) + 
     sinb^4 (Rl\[Lambda]5 + \[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4) + 
     cosb^2 sinb^2 (-4 Rl\[Lambda]5 + 3 \[Lambda]1 + 
        3 \[Lambda]2 - 4 (\[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4))))}}
ele12 = {{1/
2 a (2 I (cosb^2 + sinb^2) (cosb^2 Ir\[Lambda]5 + 
     2 cosb (-Ir\[Lambda]6 + Ir\[Lambda]7) sinb - 
     Ir\[Lambda]5 sinb^2) v + 
  3 a (cosb^4 Rl\[Lambda]7 + 
     3 cosb^2 (Rl\[Lambda]6 - Rl\[Lambda]7) sinb^2 - 
     Rl\[Lambda]6 sinb^4 + 
     cosb sinb^3 (Rl\[Lambda]5 - \[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]3 +\[Lambda]4) - 
     cosb^3 sinb (Rl\[Lambda]5 - \[Lambda]2 + \[Lambda]3 +\[Lambda]4)))}}

ele22 = {{1/(
2 cosb sinb) (2 Rlm12^2 sinb^4 - cosb^6 Rl\[Lambda]6 v^2 - 
  Rl\[Lambda]7 sinb^6 v^2 + 
  cosb^4 (2 Rlm12^2 - 
     sinb^2 (12 a^2 Rl\[Lambda]7 + 
        6 I a Ir\[Lambda]5 v + (2 Rl\[Lambda]6 + 
           Rl\[Lambda]7) v^2)) + 
  cosb^2 (4 Rlm12^2 sinb^2 - 
     sinb^4 (12 a^2 Rl\[Lambda]6 + 
        6 I a Ir\[Lambda]5 v + (Rl\[Lambda]6 + 
           2 Rl\[Lambda]7) v^2)) + 
  cosb sinb^5 (6 I a Ir\[Lambda]6 v - 2 Rl\[Lambda]5 v^2 + 
     3 a^2 \[Lambda]1) + 
  cosb^5 sinb (6 I a Ir\[Lambda]7 v - 2 Rl\[Lambda]5 v^2 + 
     3 a^2 \[Lambda]2) + 
  2 cosb^3 sinb^3 (3 I a (Ir\[Lambda]6 + Ir\[Lambda]7) v - 
     2 Rl\[Lambda]5 v^2 + 
     3 a^2 (Rl\[Lambda]5 + \[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4)))}}

rules3 = {\[Lambda]1 -> 0.5, \[Lambda]2 -> 0.5, \[Lambda]3 -> 
0.5, \[Lambda]4 -> 0.5, Rl\[Lambda]5 -> 0.5, Rl\[Lambda]6 -> 0.5, Rl\[Lambda]7 -> 0.5, Ir\[Lambda]5 -> 0.5, Ir\[Lambda]6 -> 0.0, Ir\[Lambda]7 -> 0.0, v -> 246, cosb^2 + sinb^2 -> 1, cosb -> 0.85, sinb -> 0.85, a -> 1};


In[88]:= Mat = {{ele11, ele12}, {ele12, ele22}} /. rules3 // Simplify
Out[88]= {{{{0. + 88.8675 I}}, {{0. + 0. I}}}, {{{0. + 
 0. I}}, {{(-126359. - 385.241 I) + 2.89 Rlm12^2}}}}

In[89]:= Det[Mat]
During evaluation of In[89]:= Det::matsq: Argument {{{{0. +88.8675 I}},{{0. +0. I}}},{{{0. +0. I}},{{(-126359.-385.241 I)+2.89 Rlm12^2}}}} at position 1 is not a non-empty square matrix.
Out[89]= Det[{{{{0. + 88.8675 I}}, {{0. + 0. I}}}, {{{0. + 
  0. I}}, {{(-126359. - 385.241 I) + 2.89 Rlm12^2}}}}]

Sorry for the large MWE, but wanted to clear my problem as much as possible! Please help!

You do not need {{}} in the specification of matrix elements.

Dimension[Mat] gives {2,2,1,1}, should be {2,2}

@yarchik then how to define the 2X2 matrix elements ?

I'm following this reference link to define matrix elements.

The Reference tells you that a 2x2 matrix is written as {{a,b},{c,d}}. Instead of whatever your elements ele... are, consider them as a, b, c, d instead. Then you see that instead of numbers (as they should) they are 1x1 matrices. Which are NOT numbers. This is because you used two {{}} for the ELEMENTS of the matrix, rather than the matrix.

Without the curly brackets {{...}}( see @yarchik's helpful comment) your code evaluates
ele11 = 1/
   2 a (2 I (cosb^2 + sinb^2) (cosb^2 Ir\[Lambda]6 + 
       cosb Ir\[Lambda]5 sinb + Ir\[Lambda]7 sinb^2) v + 
    a (6 cosb^3 (-Rl\[Lambda]6 + Rl\[Lambda]7) sinb + 
       6 cosb (Rl\[Lambda]6 - Rl\[Lambda]7) sinb^3 + 
       cosb^4 (Rl\[Lambda]5 + \[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4) + 
       sinb^4 (Rl\[Lambda]5 + \[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4) + 
       cosb^2 sinb^2 (-4 Rl\[Lambda]5 + 3 \[Lambda]1 + 3 \[Lambda]2 - 
          4 (\[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4)))) 
ele12 = 1/
   2 a (2 I (cosb^2 + sinb^2) (cosb^2 Ir\[Lambda]5 + 
       2 cosb (-Ir\[Lambda]6 + Ir\[Lambda]7) sinb - 
       Ir\[Lambda]5 sinb^2) v + 
    3 a (cosb^4 Rl\[Lambda]7 + 
       3 cosb^2 (Rl\[Lambda]6 - Rl\[Lambda]7) sinb^2 - 
       Rl\[Lambda]6 sinb^4 + 
       cosb sinb^3 (Rl\[Lambda]5 - \[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]3 + \
\[Lambda]4) - 
       cosb^3 sinb (Rl\[Lambda]5 - \[Lambda]2 + \[Lambda]3 + \
\[Lambda]4))) 

ele22 = 1/(2 cosb sinb) (2 Rlm12^2 sinb^4 - cosb^6 Rl\[Lambda]6 v^2 - 
    Rl\[Lambda]7 sinb^6 v^2 + 
    cosb^4 (2 Rlm12^2 - 
       sinb^2 (12 a^2 Rl\[Lambda]7 + 
          
          6 I a Ir\[Lambda]5 v + (2 Rl\[Lambda]6 + 
             Rl\[Lambda]7) v^2)) + 
    cosb^2 (4 Rlm12^2 sinb^2 - 
       sinb^4 (12 a^2 Rl\[Lambda]6 + 
          6 I a Ir\[Lambda]5 v + (Rl\[Lambda]6 + 
             2 Rl\[Lambda]7) v^2)) + 
    cosb sinb^5 (6 I a Ir\[Lambda]6 v - 2 Rl\[Lambda]5 v^2 + 
       3 a^2 \[Lambda]1) + 
    cosb^5 sinb (6 I a Ir\[Lambda]7 v - 2 Rl\[Lambda]5 v^2 + 
       3 a^2 \[Lambda]2) + 
    2 cosb^3 sinb^3 (3 I a (Ir\[Lambda]6 + Ir\[Lambda]7) v - 
       2 Rl\[Lambda]5 v^2 + 
       3 a^2 (Rl\[Lambda]5 + \[Lambda]3 + \[Lambda]4))) 

rules3 = {\[Lambda]1 -> 0.5, \[Lambda]2 -> 0.5, \[Lambda]3 -> 
    0.5, \[Lambda]4 -> 0.5, Rl\[Lambda]5 -> 0.5, Rl\[Lambda]6 -> 0.5, 
   Rl\[Lambda]7 -> 0.5, Ir\[Lambda]5 -> 0.5, Ir\[Lambda]6 -> 0.0, 
   Ir\[Lambda]7 -> 0.0, v -> 246, cosb^2 + sinb^2 -> 1, cosb -> 0.85, 
   sinb -> 0.85, a -> 1};

result
Mat = {{ele11, ele12}, {ele12, ele22}} /. rules3 // Simplify
Det[Mat]
(*(34235.4 - 1.12292*10^7 I) + (0. + 256.827 I) Rlm12^2*)


Actually I used First command to remove the problem creating extra braces and was going to update that. The problem is fixed now. Thanks to both of you for your help.
